# Gorm retrieve all unique by field data prioritized by other fields

Tags: mysql, grails-orm

let's say we have the following values in the database:

```
 id label  value   client  place
  1  test  value1  a       home
  2  test  value2  a
  3  test  value3
  4  test1 value4  b
  5  test1 value5
  6  test2 value6
```

I am trying to make a GET request, that will use the parameters(client & place) and will retrieve basically all the rows(a single time based on the label) with the following priority rule:

1. if exists in the db the value that has also a client and place, take that
2. if not, take the one if it has the client set,
3. finally take the general one

So for the example above it should return:

```
  id label  value  client  place
  1  test  value1  a       home
  4  test1 value4  b
  6  test2 value6
```

I'm wondering if I can achieve this by using gorm syntax, I am trying to integrate with this:

```
  SELECT * FROM `mytable`ORDER BY label, client DESC, place DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky. I definitely do not have the fully correct answer for you as I'm using Oracle.

Oracle supports a different syntax for the JOIN (WHERE o."label" = i."label"), so I expect my solution will not work using MySQL.

This is the best I could come up with, it's working for me in Oracle. Hopefully it helps to point you in the right direction:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM MY_TABLE m
WHERE m."id" IN (
    SELECT o."id"
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT i."id", i."label", i."client", i."place"
        FROM MY_TABLE i
        ORDER BY i."label", i."client" DESC NULLS LAST, i."place" DESC NULLS LAST) o
    WHERE m."label" = o."label" AND ROWNUM = 1
);
```

The logic behind the approach is to

- order the table (i)
- select the first "id" for each distinct label (o)
- select all data by those ids (m)